# How do I use VPN only in one android application?

Tags: java, android, vpn

I need to use the built-in **VPN** in my Android application. When I open my application, I need to start **VPN** from app, and disconnect when I quit the app.

The condition is that **VPN** only works on my application and has no effect on any other app. I need some source code or solution.

Language: **JAVA {Android}**

Example Apps: **OPERA BROWSER**

link: `https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.opera.browser&hl=en_IN&gl=US`

Answer (score 0):

> When I open my application, I need to start VPN from app, and disconnect when I quit the app.

That is not an option.

> The condition is that VPN only works on my application and has no effect on any other app

The "built-in VPN" affects the entire device.

> Example Apps: OPERA BROWSER

[They have their own VPN](https://www.opera.com/features/free-vpn) built into their app. They are not using a device-supplied VPN.